# How to send data without open an activity?

Tags: android

In my app I can get my updated location & call log history on TextView & pressing a button, I can also send the data to a specific email address(here I use a  server). 
Now, I want to send the same data to the email but without pressing any button. I mean, after installing the app I will visit the activity only once to save the email ID & will not visit anymore but whenever my location changed or my call log history updated app will automatically send the updates to the mail. 
How can I do this? If somebody have any idea please suggest me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To send email in android without user's action, you can do it via SMTP. It has provided in JavaMail API that is not usable in Android because of AWT dependencies. But there is an implementation for Android that cleans these dependencies. [Here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/javamail-android/) you can find it. To send mail using it, follow [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-using-smtp-java.html). To listen device location change, you can listen to location updates. See [this](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates).

Comment: Thank you. Let me try :)